# Read file in level up directory

Tags: php, nginx

Today Im trying to open my config file which is in a level up where the .php is executed.

However, it drops me a blank page (I assume that the file is not being read correctly). Im just starting at php thats why this could sound so ridiculous

Im currently running PHP 7.3 (as far as I read dirname function has changed in this version)

```
$fileName = "gamesettings.conf";
$upOne = dirname(__DIR__, 1);
$ficheros1  = scandir($upOne);
readfile($fileName);
exit;
```

Thanks for reading, best regards.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php), `dirname` will return the path of the directory, and if you append an integer `n` as second parameter it will go up by `n` levels.

```
echo dirname("/foo/bar/test"); // Outputs /foo/bar/test
echo dirname("/foo/bar/test", 1); // Outputs /foo/bar
```

So you are using it correctly.

Except when you read your file, you are only using the file name (which makes the `readfile` function try to find a file called `gamesettings.conf` relatively to the current file.)

You need to add the path of the parent directory(ies) to make `readfile` find a file called `gamesettings.conf` relatively to the project "top" directory:

```
$fileName = "gamesettings.conf";
$upOne = dirname(__DIR__, 1);
readfile("$upOne/$fileName");
```

This should work.